# What's the adjectival form of "data"/"datum"?

Tags: adjectives, derivational-morphology

"Informative" is the adjectival form of "information". What's the adjectival form of "data"/"datum"?

Comment: You would better provide an example sentence to show how you would want to use it in the adjectival form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Latin, *datum* is already an adjective of sorts, in so far as it is a form of the verb *do* (to give) and means 'that which is given'. If you had to make an adjective of it in English, you would have to use *given*, as in 'a given fact'.

Comment: You mean 'a *given* fact' means 'a fact that is data-generating' or 'a fact consists of data.'?  In Latin, '*datum*' is the a inflective form of the verb 'do'?  Etymologically, this might make sense, but does **informative:information<>given:data** really look like a good analogy for modern English?

Comment: Given facts, data, are those on which an argument is based and which, rather like axioms, require no further investigation for the purpose of any current discussion. Yes, _datum_ is the nominative and accusative neuter singular of the past participle of the Latin verb _do_, meaning 'give'. In that form, some Latin grammars describe it as the supine.

Comment: Just as a comment the french for **data** is **les données** or **the given things**

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use **data-generating** if I had to.

Comment: Comparing to the above two suggestions, I like **data-generating** more.  But I wonder if there is a better verb than "generating".  I.e. it's not necessarily "generating" that I want to emphasize.

Answer (score 2):

How about ***statistical***?

I realize it's not the same root word, but my dictionary<sup>1</sup> shows a credible thread:

> **statistical** (*adjective*): of or relating to the use of statistics
>
> **statistics** (*plural noun*):
>   the practice or science of collecting and analyzing numerical ***data*** in large quantities, esp. for the purpose of inferring proportions in a whole from those in a representative sample.
>
> **statistic** (*noun*):
>   a fact or piece of ***data*** from a study of a large quantity of numerical data

So long as the data is *numerical* or *quantitative*, at least, that word seems to work (although it might be more of a stretch if applied to, say, *demographical* data.)

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>(Definitions from NOAD; emphasis added.)</sub>

Comment: Data by itself doesn't immediately imply statistical.  Statistical is a particular way of looking at data pertaining to seeking patterns, or various macroscopic qualitative or quantitative features.  So I don't really think *statistical* plays the exactly accurate role in analogy **informative:information<>statistical:data**.

Comment: I agree it's not an "exactly accurate role" in the analogy, but, given the alternatives provided, it's still worth considering. It may not always work, but it could be useful in many contexts.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the term "data-driven" might be apt?

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/data-driven

> **data-driven** (adjective)
>   based on or decided by collecting and analysing data
>   • *We use a data-driven approach*: *all decisions are based on careful consideration of the evidence.*

Comment: Thank you kindly for your edit. I deeply appreciate it. :) :D

Answer (score 1):

It can be *data based*. Not actually sure about it but I hope it's so.